# how to add annotation to the type of the argument?

Tags: .net, f#

A unique overload for method 'GetBytes' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

[image]

Comment: You can specify type on any expression with colon `(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes : string -> byte[]) >> Seq.filter(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you dispense with the function composition the issue goes away

```
let terminalStringWidth (s: string) = 
    System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes s
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> int x <> 0b0) 
    |> Seq.length
```

or explicitly tell the compiler the type you want to select

```
let terminalStringWidth s = 
    (System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes : string -> _)
    >> Seq.filter (fun x -> int x <> 0b0) 
    >> Seq.length
```

personally I wouldnt write this point free, I used to always try to, but actually for me, it got in the way.